# Can anyone figure out why my jquery function slide up and down is not working properly on my first li tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript function doit() does not work properly. I dont know why? any suggestions? 
I have java script code here but can update if the html needs to be looked at. Here is the code: This has been modified

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Something</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
    </script>
    <script src="functions.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document.body).ready(function () 
    {

        $("#video").slideDown("slow");
        $("#first").css("background-color","#CCC");


        $("#second").click( function () {
                $("#video").slideUp("slow",function() {
                    $("#first").css("background-color","#666");
                });
                $("#video2").slideDown("slow",function() {
                    $("#second").css("background-color","#CCC");
                }); 
        });



        $("#first").click(doit("first"));

    });
    function doit(x)
    {
        if(x.equals("first"))
        {
            $("#video2").slideUp("slow",function() {
                    $("#second").css("background-color","#666");
                });
                $("#video").slideDown("slow",function() {
                    $("#first").css("background-color","#CCC");
                }); 
        }
        else if(x == "second")
        {

        }
        else if(x == "third")
        {
        }
    }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id ="content">
        <div id="header"> 
            <h1>Picture</h1>
        </div>
        <span id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li id="first">Main Tab</li>
                <li id="second"> Video Tab</li>
                <li id="third">Third Tab</li>
                <li id="fourth">Fourth Tab</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <iframe id ="video" style="display:none" width="560" height="315"   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Sv6dMFF_yts" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <iframe id ="video2" style="display:none" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/g16eL-_HlvI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <div class="square" style="position:absolute; left: 1000px; top:500px;"></div>
        <div class="square" style="position:absolute; left: 1130px; top:500px;"></div>
        <div class="square" style="position:absolute; left: 1160px; top:500px;"></div>
        <div class="square" style="position:absolute; left: 1190px; top:500px;"></div>
        <div class="footer">2012
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try changing `$("#first").click(doit("first"));` to `$("#first").click(function() { console.log(doit("first")); });` for starters and see what comes up

Comment: Second, give us some html or a jsFiddle and i'm sure it can be fixed pretty quick and easy

Comment: The console.log function is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$("#first").click(doit("first"));
```

The `doit` function will execute at once (i.e when that line is executed, not when #first is clicked), and its return value will get attached to the click handler. In this case nothing is returned, and consequently nothing happens when you click it.

What you want to do is this:

```
$("#first").click(function(){
    doit("first");
});
```

Also, as others have mentioned, swap `if (x.equals("first"))` to `if (x == "first")`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `if(x.equals("first"))` 
It should be `if(x == "first")`

Answer (score 0):

Without any mention of an error or where you think the code is failing, I'd have to say that this line is probably not doing what you want:

```
if(x.equals("first"))
```

You'll probably want that to be this:

```
if(x == "first")
```

You want to check the equality of the *value* not the equality of the object reference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `.equals()` method doesn't exist. You need to do a comparison like so:

```
if(x === "first") {}
```

[Here is a list of all methods available to String instances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2)